# Python script to convert hexadecimal to decimal

Tags: python

I've written the python script below to convert hexadecimal to decimal.
It seems to work fine, at least as long as the hexadecimal has less then 8 characters .

What did I do wrong ? Tnx !

```
""" converts hexidecimal to decimal"""
def HextoDec (string):
    ret = 0
    for i in string : 
        hex = "0123456789ABCDEF"
        value= hex.index(i) # 0 to 15  
        index = string.index(i)
        power = (len(string) -(index+1)) #power of 16
        ret += (value*16**power)
    return ret
print(HextoDec("BAABFC7DE"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
index = string.index(i)
```

`index()` returns the position of the *first* match. If the hex number contains any duplicate characters, you'll get the wrong index for all the repeats.

Instead of searching for the index, get it directly when you're iterating:

```
for index, i in enumerate(string):
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a much easier way to convert hexadecimal to decimal without the use of a custom function - just use the built-in `int()` function like so:

```
int("BAABFC7DE", base=16) #replace BAABFC7DE with any hex code you want
```

But if you do want to use a custom function, then Barmar's answer is the best.

Comment: Thanks I know, but since I'm following a course with both an intro to Python and a chapter on hexadecimals, this seemed like a usefull exercise :-)

Comment: Of course, I was just suggesting a much friendlier way, hence the reason I referred to @Barmar's answer as being the most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As Barmar pointed out. The issued is with the line

> index = string.index(i)

Which returns first match. Try this:

```
def HextoDec (string):
    ret = 0
    for i,d in enumerate(string) : 
        hex = "0123456789ABCDEF"
        value= hex.index(d) # 0 to 15
        #index = string.index(i)
        power = (len(string) -(i+1)) #power of 16
        ret += (value*16**power)
    return ret
```